# why laravel pagination just work with reture and not custom response Handler

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-pagination

if you see this code:

```
use ResponseHandler;
    public function search(SoundFilter $soundFilter) {

        $sounds = Sound::query();
        $sounds->filter($soundFilter);
//        dd($sounds->toSql());
        $sounds = $sounds->paginate(1);
        $this->setResponseStatus(1);
        $this->setResponseStatusCode(200);
        $this->setResponseData([
            'sounds'    => new SoundsCollection($sounds),
        ]);
        $this->ajaxResponse();
        return $this->response();
    }
```

i want soundsCollection($sounds) returen paginate result but it will send only data

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "messages": [],
    "statusCode": 200,
    "data": {
        "sounds": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "منی که عشق با روضه فهمیدم",
                "slug": "",
                "type": 2,
                "description": "<p dir=\"rtl\" style=\"text-align:center\"><strong>متن شعر<\/strong><\/p>",
                "likes": 0,
                "downloads": 0,
                "views": 0,
                "created_at": "2019-08-02 20:09:45",
                "updated_at": "2019-08-03 18:45:49",
                "sort_order": 0,
                "status": 1,
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

but when i do this code :

```
$sounds = Sound::query();
        $sounds->filter($soundFilter);
//        dd($sounds->toSql());
        $sounds = $sounds->paginate(1);
        $this->setResponseStatus(1);
        $this->setResponseStatusCode(200);
//        $this->setResponseData([
////            'sounds'    => new SoundsCollection($sounds),
////        ]);
        $this->ajaxResponse();
        return new SoundsCollection($sounds);
```

i will get pagination result

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "منی که عشق با روضه فهمیدم",
            "slug": "",
            "type": 2,
            "description": "<p dir=\"rtl\" style=\"text-align:center\"><strong>متن شعر<\/strong><\/p>",
            "likes": 0,
            "downloads": 0,
            "views": 0,
            "created_at": "2019-08-02 20:09:45",
            "updated_at": "2019-08-03 18:45:49",
            "sort_order": 0,
            "status": 1,
        }
    ],
    "links": {
        "first": "http:\/\/madahi.test\/api\/v1.0\/search?page=1",
        "last": "http:\/\/madahi.test\/api\/v1.0\/search?page=3",
        "prev": null,
        "next": "http:\/\/madahi.test\/api\/v1.0\/search?page=2"
    },
    "meta": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "from": 1,
        "last_page": 3,
        "path": "http:\/\/madahi.test\/api\/v1.0\/search",
        "per_page": 1,
        "to": 1,
        "total": 3
    }
}
```

which function i should call or waht i should do to get same result but with my custom response handler how to force collection return paginate result
i want i have link, meta in first result

Comment: What does `setResponseData` do?

Comment: @levi it will add Sounds to $json['data'] that will apear into response

Answer (score 0):

i found it and share it for other people if have same problem:
because i use seprate ResponseHandler and it will reutrn an JsonResponse object 
it is the data i send to resposnse with responseHandler

```
// trait :  ResponseHandler.php
new JsonResponse($json, $json['statusCode'], $this->headers);
```

and when i call this code it will retun another JsonResponse

```
'sounds'    => new SoundsCollection($sounds),
// Or
'sounds'    => (new SoundsCollection($sounds))->toResponse($request)
```

so the above JsonResponse will ignore pagination data the solution is :

```
 'sounds'    => (new SoundsCollection($sounds))->toResponse($request)->getData()
```

and it will work

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "messages": [],
    "statusCode": 200,
    "data": {
        "sounds": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "منی که عشق با روضه فهمیدم",
                    "slug": "",
                    "type": 2,
                    "description": "<p dir=\"rtl\" style=\"text-align:center\"><strong>متن شعر<\/strong><\/p>",
                    "likes": 0,
                    "downloads": 0,
                    "views": 0,
                    "created_at": "2019-08-02 20:09:45",
                    "updated_at": "2019-08-03 18:45:49",
                    "sort_order": 0,
                    "status": 1,
                }
            ],
            "links": {
                "first": "http:\/\/madahi.test\/api\/v1.0\/search?page=1",
                "last": "http:\/\/madahi.test\/api\/v1.0\/search?page=3",
                "prev": null,
                "next": "http:\/\/madahi.test\/api\/v1.0\/search?page=2"
            },
            "meta": {
                "current_page": 1,
                "from": 1,
                "last_page": 3,
                "path": "http:\/\/madahi.test\/api\/v1.0\/search",
                "per_page": 1,
                "to": 1,
                "total": 3
            }
        }
    }
}
```